# Changing an area from clickable to "unclickable"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am programming a javascript based tic tac toe game.

I want to make it so that after the user completes a game, none of the open spaces are clickable again, therefore making it so that they cannot continue to add x's to the board.

Currently I begin the program using JQuery to make spots of the grid like so:

```
 $('#upleft').click(function()
```

the rest occurs correctly, but this is what makes it clickable to my understanding.

Each space while having the unique id specified above also has a class of tictactoe, and so I thought to turn off the "clickability" by doing this:

```
 $(document).off("click", ".tictactoe");
```

However it does not seem to be working. Any suggestions? I'm open to other functions and such. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the `off` method on the element.

```
$('#upleft').on('click', function() { });
//...
$('.tictactoe').off('click');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$('.tictactoe').off("click");
```

Comment: You spotted a typo! I've corrected it now. It still does not work (that's how I have it in my actual code)

Comment: Right on the money! Thanks so much!